# Get Google Plus cover URL by user_id

Tags: google-plus, google-oauth, cover

Is there a way to get the profile picture for a google+ account by using an URL ?

I know that we can get the photo by doing something like: https://plus.google.com/s2/photos/profile/1234567890?sz=200 and I need something similar to get the profile cover photo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the URL you have, if you have the user's Google+ ID, you can then retrieve their profile, which contains a link to their profile. An example:

[Api Explorer Demo of Retrieving a Cover Photo](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.get?userId=%252BGusClass&fields=cover%252FcoverPhoto%252Furl&_h=2&)

Set the fields value to `cover/coverPhoto/url` if it's not getting added automatically.

Answer (score 3):

There is not a link to access profile photos through the Google+ API.  The best way to do this would be to make a GET request to the [`people.get` API endpoint](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get), as follows:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{userId}
```

That will return a [`Person` resource](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people), which will contain the user's profile image under the id `image`.