# How to get one's own cover photo URL with the Google Plus API

Tags: json, google-plus

I need some assistance with using the Google + API and really simply (unless you're me) getting the URL of my own cover photo. I've tried following along with the API documentation and some tutorials online, but I'm pretty lost and don't even know what language the GET needs to be in. In addition, I know basic Javascript and PHP so I may not be able to write the request that is needed.

Essentially this is a repeat question of '[Get Google Plus cover URL by user_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055914/get-google-plus-cover-url-by-user-id)', but I would like a more in depth explanation.

My request is:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/%2BJeremyMalais?fields=cover%2FcoverPhoto%2Furl&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer
```

And I just need the `url` from the response:

```
{
 "cover": {
  "coverPhoto": {
   "url": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/etc.JPG"
  }
 }
}
```

I've turned on the Google+ API and have created an OAuth Client ID and a Public API Access Key (for browser applications).

What's next?

Comment: GET is a method of http, other methods include POST, PUT, DELETE and more.

So GET is not in a language exactly, but how you request stuff over http (a specification).

Your question lacks a lot of details;
Are you trying to get the response server or client side?

Comment: I'm looking for this to be client side.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what to do using PHP:

```
<?php
    $id = "YOUR_GOOGLE_PLUS_ID";
    $key = "YOUR_API_KEY";
    $output = "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/" . $id . "?fields=cover%2FcoverPhoto%2Furl&key=" . $key;
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($output));
    if (!($json === true || $json === false || $json === null))
        echo $json->cover->coverPhoto->url;
?>
```